# Dynamic MongoDB query

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

I have a JSON which contains some filter criteria like

```
{
    {
       field: 'estimatedTime',
       operator: '<='
       value: '50'
    },
    {
       field: 'message',
       operator: 'contains'
       value: 'meow'
    },
    ...
}
```

I correctly translate it in a query

> {'$elemMatch': { 'estimatedTime': {'$lte': 50}, 'message': {'$regex': 'meow'}}}

I'm using elemMatch since the query needs to be run on a JSON with a nested array. Let's call that array field 'properties'.
I launched the query on the MongoDB and it works fine.

Problem is when I use the query in Node.js

```
users_with_filters.forEach(function(value) {
                console.log(res.id);
                var criteria = {};
                criteria['$elemMatch'] = JSON.parse(value.filter[0].filter).criteria;
                console.log(criteria);
                Topic.find({'_id': new ObjectId('599ea4b7b924bf16409c67cc'), 'properties': criteria}, function (err, person) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);           
                        //return res.send(err);
                    }
                    console.log("Topic: " + person)
                });
            })
```

**console.log("Topic: " + person)** prints nothing at all.

While if I hardcode the query like:

```
Topic.find({'_id': new ObjectId('599ea4b7b924bf16409c67cc'), 'properties': {'$elemMatch': { 'estimatedTime': {'$lte': 50}, 'message': {'$regex': 'meow'}}}}, function (err, person) ...
```

**console.log("Topic: " + person)** prints what I am looking for.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@JackLametta what happen here is that

The database queries are always slow compared to the normal statement and also to 'JSON.parse', so when you use the `criteria` and you write in database the query, we would have a new 'criteria'.

So you can use this approach.

```
 users_with_filters.forEach(function(value) {
                console.log(res.id);
             someone(JSON.parse(value.filter[0].filter ).criteria);
            })
 function someone(data){
     var criteria = {};
                criteria['$elemMatch'] = data;
                console.log(criteria);
                Topic.find({'_id': new ObjectId('599ea4b7b924bf16409c67cc'), 'properties': criteria}, function (err, person) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);           
                        //return res.send(err);
                    }
                    console.log("Topic: " + person)
                });

 }
```

Or use promise and async instead of foreach.

Comment: what you are getting when you print  console.log(criteria); in my approach